# 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'done' as well as code freezes

Tags: python, turtle-graphics, python-turtle

I came across an exercise, and I cannot figure out how to do it.

The exercise:

Write a function named Triangle1 that takes three integers as input variables, and prints either “Yes” or “No,” depending on whether you can, or cannot, form a triangle from sides with the given lengths. In addition, I need to, "form the triangle using python turtle with the turtle creating angles based on the given sides”.

This is what I've tried so far. However I constantly get errors pertaining to either a part of turtle not being defined in some way:

```
AttributeError: 'Turtle' object has no attribute 'done'
```

or having the process finish with an exit code of 0.
I think it might be related to using a specific program, but I can't seem to figure out how to fix this problem.

```
from math import *
import turtle


def draw_triangle(board, angles, sides):
  A, B, C = angles
  a, b, c = sides
  # draw side a
  board.forward(a)
  # Change direction and draw side b
  board.left(180-C)
  board.forward(b)
  # Change direction and draw side c
  board.left(180-A)
  board.forward(c)

  board.done()

def main():
  board = turtle.Turtle()

  a = (int(input("Enter a value for a:")))
  b = (int(input("Enter a value for b:")))
  c = (int(input("Enter a value for c:")))

  if a+b > c and b+c > a and a + c > b:
      print("Those ARE valid sides of a triangle")
  else:
      print("Those ARE NOT valid sides of a triangle")

  A = degrees(acos((a**2+b**2-c**2)/(2.0*a*b)))
  B = degrees(acos((b**2+c**2-a**2)/(2.0*b*c)))
  C = degrees(acos((c**2+a**2-b**2)/(2.0*a*c)))

  draw_triangle(board, [A, B, C], [a, b, c])

main()
```

I expect the output of the code to draw a triangle that changes angles based on the user inputted side lengths.

Comment: Please show a stack trace. Also, is your module named turtle.py by any chance? If so, rename it and rerun

Comment: ``done`` is a function of the ``turtle`` module, not a method of the ``turtle.Turtle`` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This revision of the code should fix the OP's stated problems as well as the trigonometry problem (i.e. the triangles should close.)  It will also use previously unused angle B to return the turtle cursor to its original heading:

```
from math import pi, acos
from turtle import Turtle, mainloop

def draw_triangle(board, angles, sides):
    A, B, C = angles
    a, b, c = sides

    # draw side a
    board.forward(a)

    # Change direction and draw side b
    board.left(pi - C)
    board.forward(b)

    # Change direction and draw side c
    board.left(pi - A)
    board.forward(c)

    # If all's correct, return to starting angle
    board.left(pi - B)

def main():
    a = int(input("Enter a value for a: "))
    b = int(input("Enter a value for b: "))
    c = int(input("Enter a value for c: "))

    if a + b > c and b + c > a and a + c > b:
        print("Those ARE valid sides of a triangle")
    else:
        print("Those ARE NOT valid sides of a triangle")

    A = acos((b**2 + c**2 - a**2) / (2.0 * b * c))
    B = acos((c**2 + a**2 - b**2) / (2.0 * c * a))
    C = acos((a**2 + b**2 - c**2) / (2.0 * a * b))

    board = Turtle()
    board.radians()

    draw_triangle(board, [A, B, C], [a, b, c])

    mainloop()

main()
```

The `board.done()` was invalid as `board` is a turtle an `done()` is a screen method.  The trigonometry problem was that the three angle calculations were assigned incorrectly.

Finally, I switched the turtle to *radians* so that all the math can be done without the conversions to degrees.